# why I cannot got the correct value from array?

Tags: android, textview

update:

I use these methods to get my data, but I have some issues.

This is full code.

```
holder.tags.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String data = newFeedModel.getFeedTags();
            String[] items = data.split("#");
            for (String item : items)
            {
                sb.append("#"+item+"\n");
                holder.tags.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        for(int i =1 ; i <= items.length;i++){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),items[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            //Log.d("AS",sb.toString());
            holder.tags.setText(sb.toString());
```

The input data is

```
"FeedTags": "#utas#utaslife#sandybay"
```

So I need to split "#" char to realize my target.

The first bug, I just have 3 tags, but I got 4 tags.

```
#
#utas
#utaslife
#sandybay
```

Second issues, when I onclick the tags, but always show me sandy-bay.....

Comment: var feedTags = FeedTags.split("#").toArray()  ... or so ... and then add # to every string in the list

Comment: so I need to split in php?

Comment: just use String.split("#") function. it gives you an array of strings. in your example when you split it you get { "utas" , "life" , "study" }

Comment: i Android studio :)

Answer (score 1):

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String data = newFeedModel.getFeedTags();
        String[] items = data.split("#");
        for (String item : items)
        {
            if(!item.isEmpty()){
                sb.append("#"+item+"\n");
            }
        }
        holder.tags.setText(sb.toString());
```

Use StringBuilder to create your string and set it to the view.

Currently in your code, you're setting a new string to the view in the loop.

Comment: thx bro, but has a little problem, the result is #, #utas,#utaslife,#sandybay, I have 3 tags, but it show me 4 tags.  how can remove to first "#" ?   And is it can individual click ? I mean, when I click #utas then it's can got #utas , if click #utaslife can got #utaslife.

Comment: because I need to get value then onclick to other Activity to do search

Comment: @Stanley according to the code, it should not give 4 tags. Can you add your onClick code to get a better understanding?

Comment: I update the context. Could you check it? @ depressedDarthVader

Comment: Hi bro, do u know, how can change to use spannableStringBuilder?

Comment: @Stanley I have edited my answer, you need to check for empty of the item using if condition.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Kotlin split function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) with delimiters arg = "#". `split("#")` on your `FeedTags` String from your response.